# Debugging strange javascript behavior

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, firebug

I have a page that uses JQuery UI Tabs and some other bits and pieces. When a user opens this page and quickly clicks on some tab, after a second or so the page reverts to the first tab again!

I am trying to use Firebug to see what's going on, but as far as I can see, when that reversion occurs the `body` tag highlights, but nothing within it. I am a novice with Firebug - how can I use it to better understand what's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only take a guess without a concrete example, but it sounds you're initialising the tabs twice. The tabs must already be enabled which is allowing the initial navigation between tabs. Then a second initialisation of the tabs is resetting the view back to the first tab.

You are initialising the tabs inside `$(document).ready` and not `window.onload`, right?

Comment: you were right about the tabs being initialized twice. Thank you!